# nested attr with factory on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a valid factory with nested attrs but can't figure out how to do it. I can't do it with after create, since thanks to the validation on product creation the nested attributes should be created as well.

How can I create a valid factory?

product.rb

```
has_many :industry_products, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
has_many :industries, through: :industry_products
has_many :product_features, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_competitions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_usecases, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry_products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_features, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_competitions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_usecases, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
validate :product_industries_limit
validate :product_features_limit
validate :product_competitions_limit
validate :product_usecases_limit

# other 3 validation method (features, competitions, usecases) are the same
def product_industries_limit
  if self.industries.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count > 5
    self.errors.add :base, "You can't choose more than 5 industries."
  elsif self.industries.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).blank?
    self.errors.add :base, "You have to choose at least 1 industry."
  end
end
```

factories

```
factory :product, class: Product do
  name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  company { Faker::Company.name }
  website { 'https://example.com' }
  oneliner { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  user

  trait :product_with_nested_attrs do
    after(:create) do |product|
      create(:product_competititon, product: product)
      create(:product_usecase, product: product)
      create(:product_feature, product: product)
    end
  end

  trait :with_children do
    ignore do
      product_competition { build :product_competition }
      product_usecase { build :product_usecase }
      product_feature { build :product_feature }
    end

    after(:build) do |product, evaluator|
      if evaluator.product_competitions.present?
        product.product_competitions = evaluator.product_competitions
      else
        product.product_competitions << evaluator.product_competition
      end

      if evaluator.product_usecases.present?
        product.product_usecases = evaluator.product_usecases
      else
        product.product_usecases << evaluator.product_usecase
      end

      if evaluator.product_features.present?
        product.product_features = evaluator.product_features
      else
        product.product_features << evaluator.product_feature
      end
    end
  end

  trait :with_product_all do
    ignore do
      product_competititon { build :product_competititon }
      product_usecase { build :product_usecase }
      product_feature { build :product_feature }
    end

    after(:build) do |product, evaluator|
     # If you have to skip validation, add the following line.
      product.class.skip_callback(:save, :after, :product_competitions_limit)
      product.product_competitions = evaluator.product_competitions

      product.class.skip_callback(:save, :after, :product_features_limit)
      product.product_features = evaluator.product_features

      product.class.skip_callback(:save, :after, :product_usecases_limit)
      product.product_usecases = evaluator.product_usecases
    end
  end
```

product_spec

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
let(:test_product) {create(:product, :product_with_nested_attrs) }
let
let(:product_with_attrs) { create(:product) do |product| 
                             product.product_features.create(attributes_for(:product_feature))
                             product.product_competitions.create(attributes_for(:product_competition))
                             product.product_usecases.create(attributes_for(:product_usecase))
                           end }
let(:new_product) { create(:product, :with_children) }
let(:new_product_2) { create(:product, :with_product_all) }

#this throws NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x007fa4ff6ad2d0>
it "has a valid factory" do
  attrs = attributes_for(:product).merge({
    user_id: user.id,
    product_features_attributes: attributes_for(:product_feature),
    product_usecases_attributes: attributes_for(:product_usecase),
    product_competitions_attributes: attributes_for(:product_competition),
    product_industry: attributes_for(:industry)
  })
  expect(Product.new(attrs)).to be_valid
end

#this throws: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
#You have to choose at least 1 industry., You must have at least 1 product feature., You must name at least 1 competition., You must describe at least 1 usecase.
it "has a valid factory 3" do
  expect(test_product).to be_valid
end

#this throws the same: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
#You have to choose at least 1 industry., You must have at least 1 product feature., You must name at least 1 competition., You must describe at least 1 usecase.
it "has a valid factory 4" do
  expect(product_with_attrs).to be_valid
end
```

UPDATED:

```
#this throws: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
#You have to choose at least 1 industry., You must have at least 1 product feature., You must name at least 1 competition., You must describe at least 1 usecase.
it "has a valid factory 5" do
  expect(new_product).to be_valid
end


#this throws the same: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
#You have to choose at least 1 industry., You must have at least 1 product feature., You must name at least 1 competition., You must describe at least 1 usecase.
it "has a valid factory 6" do
  expect(new_product_2).to be_valid
end

#checking puts
it "has a valid factory 7" do
  p = build(:product, :with_children)
  puts p.product_competitions #gives: #<ProductCompetition:0x007fa4fbdd6fb0>
  expect(p).to be_valid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This factory example will help to create **Product** with one **product_competition**. Having traits for each relationship will make factories more composable. You can skip validation using the **skip_callback** in the factory (If you have to).

```
 trait :with_product_competititon do
   ignore do
     product_competititon { build :product_competititon }
   end

   after(:build) do |product, evaluator|
     # If you have to skip validation, add the following line.
     product.class.skip_callback(:save, :after, :product_competitions_limit)
     product.product_competitions = [evaluator.product_competitions]
   end
 end
```

If you don't care about traits to compose the object and wish to have one factory to do everything, you can try this

```
 trait :with_children do
   ignore do
     product_competititon { build :product_competititon }
     product_usecases { build :product_usecases }
     product_features { build :product_features }
   end

  after(:build) do |product, evaluator|
    if evaluator.product_competititons.present?
      product.product_competititons = evaluator.product_competititons
    else
      product.product_competititons << evaluator.product_competititon
    end

    if evaluator.product_usecases.present?
      product.product_usecases = evaluator.product_usecases
    else
      product.product_usecases << evaluator.product_usecase
    end

    if evaluator.product_features.present?
      product.product_features = evaluator.product_features
    else
      product.product_features << evaluator.product_feature
    end
  end
```

PS: I have not tested this code.

Comment: Shishir, I've 2 questions, hope you can help me: I see the advantages of traits in general for `has_many`, etc. I prefer not to create them in factory though (again in general). I can simply like to call `let(:profile) { create(:profile, user: user }`, where I set up the relation inline. Is that a good approach? 2.: In this case where product always must have at least one of product_competition etc. I feel it's different. They always come hand in hand. So I guess 1 factory is a better fit here. Don't you agree?

Comment: Shishir, pls also check my prev comment. Why don't you use `skip_callback` for the 2nd example?

Comment: skip_callback was just an example, if you so wish to skip_validation. Its not required. To answer you question from above comment, I would use product factory to create project_completion if they always come hand in hand. I like traits because they make your data setup composible as well as legible for someone who is reading the spec.

Comment: None of these is working. I corrected some typos, but even with `skip_callback` I'm getting the validation error: At least 1 competition etc.

Comment: if you do p = build(:product); puts p.product_competititons. what do u get? Is the trait getting called?

Comment: it puts nothing at all. I placed `puts 'haha'` in the line above that and `haha` was printed.

Comment: Can u edit the question, with updated spec/factories?

Comment: Ohh I just simply copied your `build(:product)`, but if I call `build(:product, :with_children)` then I get `#<ProductCompetition:0x007fa4fbdd6fb0>`. I update the question in a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109901/discussion-between-shishir-and-szilard-magyar).

Comment: Shishir, I found the solution in this thread: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/369. `before(:create)` is the key.